# What is the best way to read config values for a python program? Is referring to an Enum class defined in another file common?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, configuration, config

For example, I might try the following config:

```
class Defaults(Enum):
    a = 1
    b = 2
```

Then from my main file, I can refer to it with:

```
import myconfig
windowSize = Defaults.a
```

This would allow me to change the enum values whenever I want to vary how my program runs. Is this a common way to use Enums in python configuration?

Comment: If you're editing the program code, I'm not sure it really counts as _configuration_.

Comment: Django uses the `settings.py` file, @John. I'd consider that configuration, and it's Python code. I'm not a big fan of that style, though.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking whether it's common to hold the configuration settings as members of an enumeration. As a more explicit example:

```
class Defaults(Enum):
    window_width = 600
    window_height = 480
    font_size = 14
```

Technically, I think that would work, but what benefit is the enumeration providing? `Enum` is useful for providing *choices* to pick from. If you really want to do this, I think a plain class, a data class, or just module-level variables would be less confusing. Django's `settings.py` configuration file seems to be the closest thing to your idea that I've seen in common use.

Your broader question is how to read configuration values for a Python program. Personally, I like the style recommended by [The Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/config).

> **The twelve-factor app stores config in *environment variables*** (often shortened to *env vars* or *env*). Env vars are easy to change between deploys without changing any code; unlike config files, there is little chance of them being checked into the code repo accidentally; and unlike custom config files, or other config mechanisms such as Java System Properties, they are a language- and OS-agnostic standard.

The most flexible way I've found is to use the `argparse` module, and use the environment variables as the defaults. That way, you can override the environment variables on the command line. Be careful about putting passwords on the command line, though, because other users can probably see your command line arguments in the process list.

Here's [an example](https://github.com/cfe-lab/MiCall/blob/v7.9wip2/micall_watcher.py#L15) that uses `argparse` and environment variables:

```
def parse_args(argv=None):
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Watch the raw data folder for new runs.',
                            formatter_class=ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument(
        '--kive_server',
        default=os.environ.get('MICALL_KIVE_SERVER', 'http://localhost:8000'),
        help='server to send runs to')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--kive_user',
        default=os.environ.get('MICALL_KIVE_USER', 'kive'),
        help='user name for Kive server')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--kive_password',
        default=SUPPRESS,
        help='password for Kive server (default not shown)')

    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    if not hasattr(args, 'kive_password'):
        args.kive_password = os.environ.get('MICALL_KIVE_PASSWORD', 'kive')
    return args
```

Setting those environment variables can be a bit confusing, particularly for system services. If you're using systemd, look at the [service unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html), and be careful to use `EnvironmentFile` instead of `Environment` for any secrets. `Environment` values can be viewed by any user with `systemctl show`.

I usually make the default values useful for a developer running on their workstation, so they can start development without changing any configuration.

If you do want to put the configuration settings in a `settings.py` file, just be careful not to commit that file to source control. I have often committed a `settings_template.py` file that users can copy.

Comment: IMHO, brilliant answer!! I was just finishing implementing pretty much the same when I decided to confirm my approach here on SO.